# What are these banana plug connectors used for?

Tags: connector, multimeter, probe

[image]

These mate with one another (in the obvious male-to-female chain). They seem to be male-to-female banana plug adapters. Maybe I am being naive, but these seem useless. What are these useful for in practice?

EDIT: They do not come apart, i.e. they are not banana plugs waiting to be soldered to wire.

The only thing I can think of is that they're intended to be connector savers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They look like they are adapters for shrouded banana plugs. As far as I can tell from your photograph, the red plugs have bodies which narrow after a ridge and the black ones have a uniformly narrower diameter. The narrow bodies fit inside the shrouds of the shrouded plugs.

[image: Shrouded banana plugs]

Comment: Huh? To me they look *exactly* the same.

Comment: @stevenvh - I meant the red plugs/adapters in the OP's photograph have bodies which narrow after a ridge. The black ones don't have this ridge but on closer inspection they seem to have a uniformly narrower diameter anyway.

Comment: I will check them when I get home--I have both the larger and smaller OD shrouded banana plug handy and I can tell you which they are.